# python 2.7 fastest dict acces for missing keys

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

if d is a dict, python docs provide us with this method:

```
dict.get = get(...)
    D.get(k[,d]) -> D[k] if k in D, else d.  d defaults to None.
```

Another famous pattern is:

```
try:
    D[k]:
except:
    d
```

But in my benchmarks (done with timeit), i have found that the following approach is the best:

```
if k in D:
    D[k]
else:
    d
```

the try/except pattern IS the fastest if no exceptions are raised, but if no exceptions are raised, then we don't need this pattern.  I now need to refactor all my code, which is written with a lot of .get()'s, because i need to squeeze some performance on a limited system. Am i correct or wrong? Why is the try/except pattern recommended when it looks like it's the slowest?

Comment: What is the question? Whether we can replicate your benchmark results? Whether one should use try/except even when no missing keys are to be expected? Or whether it's worth to refactor your code?

Comment: As you say yourself, that very much depends on how often you expect a missing key (and possibly the size of the dict). If you expect to come across missing keys often and you're performance critical, you may rethink whether you should use dicts and use another data structure instead.

Comment: Never use plain `except:`, use `except KeyError:` instead. Otherwise you will be catching syntax errors and keyboard interrupts as well.

Comment: I'm willing to bet that `dict.get` is not the slowest part of your program. Have you tried [profiling](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) it? Try running it with `python -m profile` and see what's really slowing you down. If that fails, try posting you code to the [code review stack exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) and see what people suggest there.

Comment: Related: [Python Forgiveness vs. Permission and Duck Typing](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/175655)

Comment: @Anton: no, syntax errors are only thrown by the compiler, so unless there is an `exec` or `import` or `eval` in there the syntax error is thrown before the code is executed.

Comment: @Anton: however, `KeyboardInterrupt`, `SystemExit`, and `GeneratorExit` should not be caught lightly. And neither should most other exceptions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, you are correct about what can cause a SyntaxError, so yes, my example was a bit far fetched. Thanks for pointing that out! I stand by my point that plain `except` most often is to be avoided, and as you noted it does in fact catch SyntaxError in case of import etc.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `D[k] if k in D else d` pattern is about twice faster than .get, at least for some usages.

.get

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'D={}; k=xrange(0,100000)' 'D.get(k)'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0934 usec per loop
```

if/else

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'D={}; k=xrange(0,100000)' 'D[k] if k in D else None'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0487 usec per loop
```

Comment: This is what i mean. It shouldn't be twice as slow.

Comment: Why use a range as an index?

Comment: No real reason, just for test variation. It shouldn't make a difference but hey..

Comment: Why is it faster is difficult to answer without profiling the C code for the dictionary object against the compiled bytecode for `D[k] if k in D else None`. .get is written in C while the python code is interpreted when you run it, so its performance will vary depending on the interpreter you use. Dictionary code is at [https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/dictobject.c#l2300]. If I had to guess it would be because of the hashing of the key in the dict object C code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should give `pypy` a try and compile that on your embedded system. `if-then-else` and `get` have similar results. Some benchmarks:

PyPy:

```
$ pypy3 -m timeit -s 'd={}; k=0' 'd[k] if k in d else None'
1000000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0008 usec per loop
$ pypy3 -m timeit -s 'd={}; k=0' 'd.get(k)'                
1000000000 loops, best of 3: 0.000803 usec per loop
```

Python 3:

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'd={}; k=0' 'd.get(k)'                                                                                                                                                     1 ↵
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.101 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'd={}; k=0' 'd[k] if k in d else 0'     
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0372 usec per loop
```

Comment: I know pypy is faster, but i can't use it. I'm also limited to python 2.7.

Comment: @user37203 PyPy supports 2.7. Why can't you use it? Not your own system?

Comment: our code uses a few libraries that don't support pypy. It's just not worth it. 
On every code loop there are tens of dict.gets. My assumption is that i can lower the request time if i replace those with a different pattern (if then else)